# JTable перезаполнение таблицы при изменении данных

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно перезаполнить таблицу при изменении данных модели, читал что есть подобные слушатели, однако нормального примера не нашел.
Необходимо что бы при нажатии таблица автоматически перерисовывалась.

```
public class PP extends JFrame {
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

    public PP() throws HeadlessException {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(levayaJTable(), "Center");
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setVisible(true);
        JButton jButton=new JButton("Изменить");
        jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i=0;i<levayaJTable().getRowCount();i++)
                {
                    data=new HashMap<>();
                    data.put("1. Фамилия","Иванов");
                    data.put("2. Имя","Иван");
                    data.put("3. Отчество","Иванович");
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(jButton, "South");
    }
    private JTable levayaJTable() {
        String[] dannie = new String[]{
                "1. Фамилия", "2. Имя", "3. Отчество"
        };

        JTable levayaJTable = new JTable(new OsnovTable(dannie)) {
            @Override
            public void changeSelection(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, boolean toggle, boolean extend) {
                super.changeSelection(rowIndex, 1, toggle, extend);
            }
        };
        levayaJTable.setRowHeight(20);
        levayaJTable.setOpaque(false);
        levayaJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1)
                .setCellEditor(new MaskEditorA());

        return levayaJTable;
    }

    //Модель основной таблицы
    private class OsnovTable extends AbstractTableModel {
        String[] dannie;


        public OsnovTable(String[] dannie) {
            this.dannie = dannie;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return dannie.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) return dannie[rowIndex];
            if (columnIndex == 1) return data.get(dannie[rowIndex]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) return false;
            if (columnIndex == 1) return true;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            data.put(dannie[rowIndex], (String) aValue);
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PP();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена путем добавления в модель следующего метода

```
public void reload()
        {
            repaint();
            this.fireTableDataChanged();
        }
```

Соответственно там где необходимо обновить данные таблицы

```
((OsnovTable)levayaJTable().getModel()).reload();
```